# How to search a .txt file for a string and hashcode? (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, equals, readfile

Prompt: I am writing a Login program that asks the user for their username and password. All user info is stored in a password.txt file and passwords are stored as a hashcode. If the user enters an invalid username or a password that does not have the same hash as the hash in the entry, then the program should print “Unsuccessful login.” If the user enters a valid username and the password has the same hash as the hash in the entry, then the program should print “Login successful.“

The password.txt file is set up like so:

```
Real name:username:password_hash
```

**Question: How do I search a .txt for a String and hashcode?**

This is the code I have for now:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner sf = new Scanner("passwords.txt");
            String Username;
            String Password;

            System.out.println("Login ");
            System.out.println("Please Enter Username: ");
            Username = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Please Enter Password: ");
            Password = sc.next();

            String login = Username + ":" + Password.hashCode();
            System.out.println(login);

            while(sf.hasNextLine()){
                    if((login.equals(sf.nextLine().trim()))){
                            System.out.println("Login Successful!");
                            break;
                    }

                    if(!(login.equals(sf.nextLine().trim()))){
                            System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful!");

                    }
            }
```

I'm trying to search the code for a String that looks like username:hashcodePassword

Problems: The code doesn't print either if statement and gives me this error when running the program

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
        at LoginApplication.main(LoginApplication.java:29)
```

Comment: Break your task down into small steps and then try to solve each step one at a time -- divide and conquer will help you succeed. For example try just simply reading and printing a text file using a BufferedReader, and using help obtained by searching for and studying a tutorial on its use. Same for the other steps. When you get stuck at a much more specific step, and *after* you've studied the appropriate tutorials and have tried to apply them ***that's*** when you should ask a much more specific question here.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explaination: your code checks if the file has a next line, so it check the first nested **if** but here it reads a line from the file and the pointer to the file is moved to the next line. Then it checks the next **if statement** and here another line of your file is read.
The problem appears because you are actually reading two lines of file at one time.

The solution is

```
while(sf.hasNextLine()) {
                final String currentLine = sf.nextLine().trim();
                if(login.equals(currentLine)){
                        System.out.println("Login Successful!");
                        break;
                } else {
                        System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful!");
                }
        }
```

then if you need to have more if statements you can use the **currentLine** variable instead of reading another line of file.